Issue running an async method in GCP Cloud Run Serverless with Quarkus
With Quarkus running in GCP Cloud Run serverless service, I'm trying to execute an async rest client method. I have to call the API, but need to continue the code execution and not wait for API to response.
I already try CompletableFuture.runAsync and CompletionStage<Void>, but I getting jakarta.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.io.IOException: Connection was closed error when trying to, after approximately 30 seconds, and the API is not called.
Example:
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        myRestClient.myMethod();
});

I understand the CPU throttling issue running in a serverless environment, but there is a way to get this work?
